# date from number of days in R?

Tags: r, date

I have col of number of days since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC that I want to convert to date and time UTC.

I tried this:

```
 z <- Sys.time()
 j=floor(unclass(z)/86400) # the number of days since 1970-01-01 (UTC)
as.POSIXct(j, origin = "1970-01-01")
[1] "1970-01-01 05:53:22 CET"
```

But it is not correct. any idea?

Comment: The `as.POSIXct(as.numeric(z), origin = "1970-01-01")` gives the same 'z'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass to the function `as.POSIXct` the number of seconds, try this code

```
j<-17148.5625000000
as.POSIXct(j*24*60*60, origin = "1970-01-01", tz="UTC")
[1] "2016-12-13 13:30:00 UTC"
```

If you want only the day in output

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct(j*24*60*60, origin = "1970-01-01", tz="UTC"))
[1] "2016-12-13"
```

Comment: Answer changed according to this

Comment: The key is that the `POSIXct` format stores the date as seconds since an origin, thus when giving the value of the time elapsed since origin, it needs to be in the same units!